# how can sum count of parent child array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
  $foo_array = array (
                         [3533] => 4 ,
                         
                         [353] =>  3 ,
                         
                         [351] =>  2 ,
                         
                         [35] =>   0 ,

                      );
```

this is an example array, it has many elements and it is dynamic from the database, but I want to say an example for you!

each key of an array has a parent like this, for example, 353 is the parent of 3533 and ...

Now I want to sum count of each parent from childrens count. the true result of count for key 35 must be 9, but I can't receive this result! I create foreach for this array and get all parents, after that plus count of that child to each parent of that but unfortunately get a bad result!

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: Just curious, the value of the `35` key should be 1. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an array with the parent as the index and the values of parent and children:

```
foreach($foo_array as $key => $val) {
    $result[$key] = array_intersect_key($foo_array, array_flip(preg_grep("/^$key/", array_keys($foo_array))));
}
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [3533] => Array
        (
            [3533] => 4
        )
    [353] => Array
        (
            [3533] => 4
            [353] => 3
        )
    [351] => Array
        (
            [351] => 2
        )
    [35] => Array
        (
            [3533] => 4
            [353] => 3
            [351] => 2
            [35] => 0
        )
)
```

So you can then access by parent:

```
echo array_sum($result[35]);
```

Or you could use `$result[$key] = array_sum( . . . . . );` in the loop.

If you are only concerned with `35` for example then:

```
$key = 35;
$result = array_sum(array_intersect_key($foo_array, array_flip(preg_grep("/^$key/", array_keys($foo_array)))));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer ! this code done my job , but I have another question : for example we have another array that the structure is different and we must call a query to know the parent key . for example the parent of key 35 is 70 , can you answer this question with call query ?

Comment: Hi.  Please open a new question with more detail and post a link here.  Also please mark this as accepted.